# Check if file exists in Album

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I'm working on simple image manipulation program. I'm currently in phase where I have to save images:
I'm doing something like that at the moment:
[external source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769549%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

But there is a problem. Every time I want to save Image I'll override previous image. How to check if file exists in album "Saved Pictures"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know the file name, you can use something like this:

```
using (var ml = new MediaLibrary())
{
    using (var pics = ml.SavedPictures)
    {
        using (var img = pics.LastOrDefault(pic => pic.Name == FILENAME))
        {
            if (img == null)
            {
                // file doesn't exist
            }
            else
            {
                // file does exist
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you use LastOrDefault() instead of FirstOrDefault? That way iterate the full collection, and all you wanted is to check if it does exist... Even so, given that we just want a boolean, I personally would just use Any() instead :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one. to find a file in pictureAlbum

```
using (var library = new MediaLibrary())
{
   var appFolder = library.RootPictureAlbum.Albums.FirstOrDefault(al => al.Name == "folderName");
    if (appFolder != null && appFolder.Pictures.Count > 0)
    {
        var file = appFolder.Pictures.FirstOrDefault(pc => pc.Name == ("fileName"));
        if (file == null)
        {
            // file doesn't exist
        }
        else
        {
            // file does exist
        }
    }
}
```